# Ubuntu 18.04 Stop PS4 Controllers From Showing Up As Speakers?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio

When plugging in my PS4 controllers, they show up as valid audio output devices and Ubuntu automatically switches over to them for output; it is tedious to have to reselect my actual monitor speaker everytime a controller is plugged in. Is there a way to stop this from happening, or to blacklist these controllers so that they still function as a gamepad but never show up as a valid audio output?

Up-to-date Ubuntu 18.04
R7 1700 / GTX 1080 396.54
[image: View of Audio Output screen; PS4 shows as a speaker]